# Python + Dash + Bootstrap

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I'm trying to 'Pythonify' card generation in a function, but it seems to not be popping up.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, or perhaps the dashboard I'm building needs to be quite vertical. Basically, the *cardify* function doesn't generate a card.

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.MINTY])

def cardify(metricname, metricvalue, recapstring):
    dbc.Card(
        [
            dbc.CardBody(
                [
                    html.H2(metricname, className="card-title"),
                    html.H4(metricvalue, className="card-title"),
                    html.P(
                        recapstring,
                        className="card-text",
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        ],
#        style={"width": "18rem"},
        )

app.layout =  \
html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    cardify("Card Title", "Metric Value", "Some Quick Example yada yada"),
                    width={"size": 2, "order": 1, "offset": 1},
                ),
                dbc.Col(
                    dbc.Card(
                    [
                        dbc.CardBody(
                            [
                                html.H4("Card title", className="card-title"),
                                html.P(
                                    "Some quick example text to build on the card title and "
                                    "make up the bulk of the card's content.",
                                    className="card-text",
                                ),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ],
#                    style={"width": "18rem"},
                    ),
                    width={"size": 2, "order": 2},
                )           
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `cardify` needs to return `dbc.Card`.

Comment: YES! ::facepalm::